# Как указать на выбранный элемент

Tags: javascript

Скрипт

```js
function hideobj() {
this.style.display = "none";
}
document.body.hideobj();
```

```html
BODY CONTENT
```

Почему данный скрипт не скрывает элемент и выдает ошибку. B как указать на выбранный элемент в функции, через `this` Не работает.

Comment: `this` работает именно так как и ожидалось, ошибка в том, что в твоем примере у `body` **нет** метода _hideobj_, об этом говорит и ошибка _document.body.hideobj is not a function_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили функцию, а пытаетесь вызвать метод объекта.
Самый простой способ впилить функцию как метод - это взять и впилить прямо в объект:

```js
document.body.hideobj = function () {
    this.style.display = "none";
}
document.body.hideobj();
```

```html
BODY CONTENT
```

Можно тем же манером впилить функцию в прототип, тогда такая функция появится у всех объектов этого класса:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.hideobj = function () {
    this.style.display = "none";
}
document.forms[0].hideobj();
```

```html
BODY CONTENT
<form>NE BODY CONTENT</form>
```

Еще один вариант - можно воспользоваться методами [bind](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind), [call и apply](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply), чтобы передать нужный нам this :

```js
function hideobj() {
    this.style.display = "none";
}
hideobj.bind(document.forms[0])();
hideobj.call(document.forms[1]);
hideobj.apply(document.forms[2]);
```

```html
<form>Bind</form>
<form>Call</form>
<form>Apply</form>
```